# How do we find the limit of my code?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, code-review, broken-code, code

Suppose we have the following:

```
t[z_, eps_] := Module[{r, x, y}, r = Rationalize[N[z], eps];
   x = Numerator[r];
   y = Denominator[r];
   N[Log[1/y, Abs[z - x/y]]]];
```

I want to find the limit of `t[z_,eps_]` for any `z` as `eps` approaches zero.

I tried the following:

```
T[z_] := T[z] = 
  Limit[t[z, eps], eps -> 0, Analytic -> True, Direction -> 1]
```

**Edit:** I can't use `NLimit` since my version of Mathematica doesn't recognize it as a code.

When I entered a value for `z` such as the `N[2^(1/3)]`, I get:

```
ComplexInfinity
```

The reason a limit may exist is when I computed `z=N[2^(1/3)]` and `eps=N[10^(-s)]` in `t[z,epsilon]` and get:

```
Table[t[N[2^(1/3)], N[10^(-s)]], {s, 1, 20}]
```

I notice the values get smaller and smaller:

```
{2.37724, 3.32765, 2.21994, 2.41479, 2.13848, 2.36157, 2.02019, \
2.32556, 1.90144, 2.21558, 1.92533, 2.07795, 2.10586, 2.0106, \
2.14276, Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate, \
Indeterminate}
```

However for extremely small values of `eps`, `t[N[2^(1/3)],eps]` is indeterminate, for example for `eps=N[10^(-20)]` I get:

```
t[N[2^(1/3)], N[10^(-20)]]
Indeterminate
```

How do we get a value for extremely small `eps` such that `t[z,eps]` eventually converges to a value?

Moreover, how do we approximate `T[z]` without `NLimit`?

Comment: Could you add some details? Mathematically, do you know that the limit exists and is different from infinity? What value do you expect?

Comment: At least, `t[z_, eps_] := Module[{r, x, y}, r = Rationalize[N[z], eps];
   x = Numerator[r];
   y = Denominator[r];
   N[Log[1/y, Abs[z - x/y]], 100]];t[N[2^(1/3), 100], N[10^(-20), 100]]` results in `1.98713460803261520065585604185295512950000090120989878650984094255364\
13164696205073693`.

Comment: Consider `Rationalize[N[2^(2/3)], eps]` and then
`Denominator@Rationalize[N[2^(2/3)], eps]` which means you're taking the limit of `Log[1,...]`, which is infinity. If there's no closed-form formula for `t[]`, I think you will have to find the limit numerically.

Comment: @MichaelE2 How do we find the limit numerically using `NLimit`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I’m not able to compute the limit using NLimit?

Comment: @MarcoB I added details.

Comment: NLimit needs Needs["NumericalCalculus`"] then it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the lim sup for `z = 2^(2/3)` is 2 and the lim inf is 1. For Liouville's number $\lambda=\sum 10^{-n!}$, I expect the lim sup is infinity. I haven't pursued a proof, and at least in some cases, I expect the proof is probably easy.  To compute the limit as a discrete limit, we have to pick a sequence.  The limit of the convergents of the continued fraction of `2^(2/3)` seems to be 2.  Another sequence is to round to the nearest multiple of `b^-n` for n = 1, 2, 3,.... The limit of these sequences for b = 2, 3, 4,... appears to be 1.

```
tt // ClearAll;
tt // Options = {WorkingPrecision -> 32, 
   "MaxExtraPrecision" -> 100000};
itt // ClearAll; (* internal common method *)
mem : itt[z_, n_, 1, p_, maxep_] := mem =
   Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = maxep},
    Module[{r, x, y},
     r = FromContinuedFraction@ContinuedFraction[z, n];
     x = Numerator[r]; y = Denominator[r];
     If[y == 1,
      1,
      N[Log[1/y, Abs[z - x/y]], p]
      ]
     ]];
mem : itt[z_, n_, b_, p_, maxep_] := mem =
   Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = maxep},
    Module[{r, x, y},
     r = Round[z, b^-n];
     x = Numerator[r]; y = Denominator[r];
     If[y == 1,
      0, (* won't affect limit, unless it occurs infinitely often *)
           N[Log[1/y, Abs[z - x/y]], p]
      ]
     ]];
tt[z_?NumericQ, n_Integer?Positive, OptionsPattern[]] :=
  itt[z, n, 1, OptionValue@WorkingPrecision, 
   OptionValue@"MaxExtraPrecision"];
tt[z_?NumericQ, n_Integer?Positive, b_Integer?Positive, 
   OptionsPattern[]] :=
  itt[z, n, b, OptionValue@WorkingPrecision, 
   OptionValue@"MaxExtraPrecision"];
an // ClearAll;
an[z_?NumericQ, 1, Optional[b_Integer?Positive, 1]] := tt[z, 1, b];
an[z_?NumericQ, n_Integer?Positive, Optional[b_Integer?Positive, 1]] :=
   tt[z, n, b] - tt[z, n - 1, b];
```

The sum of `an` gives `tt`:

```
Sum[an[2^(2/3), n], {n, 5}]
tt[2^(2/3), 5]
(*
2.215243365028606850170915328762
2.2152433650286068501709153287624
*)
```

Summing `an` to get the limit of `tt` might have issues:

```
(* rounding to powers of 2 *)
NSum[Sum[an[2^(2/3), 4 (n - 1) + k, 2], {k, 4}], {n, Infinity}, 
 NSumTerms -> 100, WorkingPrecision -> 32]
(*
NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit::seqlim: The general form of the sequence could not be determined, and the result may be incorrect.

1.0040403804688150370981112890421
*)

(* continued fraction method *)
NSum[Sum[an[2^(2/3), 4 (n - 1) + k], {k, 4}], {n, Infinity}, 
 NSumTerms -> 100, WorkingPrecision -> 32]
(*
NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit::seqlim: The general form of the sequence could not be determined, and the result may be incorrect.

2.0067
*)
```

Seems easier just to compute a large value of `n`:

```
tt[2^(2/3), 10000, 1] (* C.F. --> 2 *)
tt[2^(2/3), 10000, 2] (* Round to b^-n --> 1 *)
tt[2^(2/3), 10000, 3]
tt[2^(2/3), 10000, 5]
tt[2^(2/3), 10000, 6]
(*
2.0001483539767939039872676736424
1.0002967802615836143572950681512
1.0003022219505058138381970338731
1.0003118354013750624713960106114
1.0001494855062849417882032219670
*)
```

You can use `DiscretePlot` on `tt` or `an` to see that the sequences are not well behaved and converge very slowly.  There may be tricks for accelerating convergence of these sequences, but I do not have the time to pursue them at this point.

Comment: Out of curiosity,  what would we get if `z` was a rational?

Comment: @Arbuja Eventually you take the log of zero in the continued fraction sequence and in any sequence that ultimately equals `z`. In the case where the denominator is not a power of the base `b`, my guess is that the limit is still 1.